# How to set the fontsize of a table footnote

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable

How can I set the font size to a 8pt and decrease the line spacing for all table footnotes in my RMarkdown document? Currently my line spacing is set to double and my font size is 12pt. I'm making a pdf document.

This is my code chunk at the moment:

```
kable(m,
    longtable = FALSE,
    format = "latex",
    booktabs = TRUE,
    align = c("l", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
    col.names = c("Prior Rating", "Aaa",    "Aa",   "A",    "Baa",  "Ba",   "B",    "Caa",  "Obs."),
    linesep = "\\addlinespace",
    caption = "Small Cooperative Transition Probability Matrix, 1996-2014"
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Terminal Rating" = 7)) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "scale_down")) %>%
  kableExtra::footnote(general_title = "Note.",
                       general = "The standard errors are in parentheses; * indicates the probability is significantly different from its corresponding probability in the unconditional matrix at the 5% level.",
                       threeparttable = TRUE,
                       footnote_as_chunk = TRUE,
                       fixed_small_size = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: It is easier to help if you create a reproducible example.